# Android String from Html or direct initialise with ∢ getting wrong String like []

Tags: android, html

I have tried to parse Html code in `String` with correct Html `code` code to get  ∢ this String but not able to get that String. also i have assign direct sign ∢ but its return [] String.

code.

```
 if (btn_tag.equals("op_sangle") { 

              str_text = " " + Html.fromHtml("&#8738;";

            //or
            // str_text = " ∢";
            }
```

here str_text = [] gets its wrong.

[image]